# Typescript How to change type based on static properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object like would behave like the following (pseudocode alert):

```
type Params = "string" | "bool" | "number" | "bigint";
type Return = Params | "void";

abstract class SignalTarget<Signals extends Record<string, { parameters: readonly Params[]; result: "void" }>> {
  static signals: Record<string, { parameters: readonly Params[]; result: "void" }>;

  _signals: Partial<Record<string, Function[]>> = {}

  connect (name: string, callback: Function) {
    const signals = this._signals[name];

    this._signals[name] ||= [
      ...(signals ?? []),
      callback
    ]
  }

  emit(name: string, ...args: any[]) {
    const signals = this._signals[name];

    (signals ?? []).map(signal => signal.call(this, ...args));
  }

  /*
  connect<Signal extends keyof Signals, Declarations extends Signals[Signal]>(name: Signal, callback: (...args: Declarations["parameters"]) => Declarations["result"]) {

  } */
}

// I want the object to be extended in a manner similar to this

class Log extends SignalTarget<{ log: { parameters: ["string"], result: "void" } }> {
  static signals = {
   log: {
     parameters: ["string"],
     result: "void"
   }
  } as const

  log (message: string) {
    console.log("message");
    this.emit("log", message);
  }
}

const logger = new Log;
logger.connect("log", (message) => console.log("The log method was called!: ", message));
```

Is there any way to implement this with TypeScript so that `logger.connect` only allows `log` as first parameter and the callback fucntion is fully typed?

Comment: please provide an example without syntax errors

Comment: This is just pseudocode. If I had an example, I wouldn't be asking a question on stack overflow...

Comment: if you don't want to spend some time fixing minor syntax problems, why do you think that somebody want's to do it ? [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) you can find an information how to write classes in TypeScript

Comment: I tried to fix it sir. @captain-yossarianfromUkraine

Comment: I'd probably use a factory function to simulate "static generics", perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAdjvN).  I feel like the code example in the question is doing a bit too much, though; is the result always `void`?  If so can we remove if from the example?  If not can we make the example work by actually returning something?  Anyway, once we clean up the example so it's clear what it's intended to do, does this approach look promising? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me)

Comment: yea I'd like to see your approach. no the functions doesn't always return void, I just didn't use the "Return" type. Also, I agree, this looks so much complicated